# Is there redundancy in the auditory system like there is in the visual system?

Tags: neuroscience

In the early visual system, there is a great deal of overlap between retinal ganglion cells, which results in redundancy of the signals that neurons carry to higher visual processing areas in the brain.

Is there a similar type of redundancy in the early auditory system?

Answer (score 2):

There is certainly redundancy in the auditory system, well demonstrated by [Gal Chechik et all](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0896627306005125)

It is also clear that there is pronounced intersensory redundacy, involving auditory systems [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1467-7687.00079)

[Another article](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0053634) discusses clear auditory redundancy in adults when participating in a task to discriminate between two sounds as quickly as possible

`...the auditory system maintains and tolerates functionally independently represented redundant and contradictory predictions.`

In terms of redundancy in development, it seems there have  been shown links in mice discussed by [Dr Thomas Braun](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1460-9568.2006.05051.x)

Hope this helps!